# How to change lots table columns datatypes from one to another in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with a lots of columns with BLOB type and I need to change it to nvarchar2.

So, to change type I can use following script:

```
alter table AUDIT_LOG
modify
   (
        column_name type_name,
        column_name2 type_name2
        -- etc
   );
```

And to get all columns with given datatype I can use the following:

```
select column_name, 'NVARCHAR2(4000)'
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'TAB_NAME' and data_type = 'BLOB';
```

But how to join this two scripts into one?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `DML` and `DDL` operation together in same query. You have to use dynamic SQL in a PL/SQL block

- Create a variable and generate the whole alter table query in it.
- Execute Immidiate

Refer this and I am sure you will be able to add rest of the logic as per your requirement.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0440__PL-SQL-Statements/EXECUTEIMMEDIATEdynamicsqltoaltersession.htm